# How to setup Windows Server 2008 for MySQL remote database connectivity?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, mysqli, windows-server-2008

I am very new to this server setup and database connectivity. I googled a lot but couldn't find the solution for it.I am developing an android application which needs to post data to remote database. Which is done.

Now i have to setup `MySQL Database` in the new `Windows Server 2008`. I have installed and managed to get access the `root` user(Which is fine). Now i want to access this database from my local computer[Which is **iMac**]. I already set the privileges by following this [link](http://chamaras.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/how-to-grant-permission-to-remote.html). When i tried to run from my web application it shows the following error.

```
 Error: unable to connect to database. Host 'xx.xx.xxx.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

**Here is my questions**

1.) How to get access to the remote MySQL database from any computer?

2.) How to run the web application in the server?Like Web Hosting i.e Do i need to setup ftp account and put the stuff over there?(`For Eg: testhost.com/connecttodatabase.php` by executing this it will execute whatever code in testhost server. But i have no idea how to do that for my server).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternately, You can also try...

```
use the_database_name;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 
the_database_name.* 
TO 
'the_user_in_php_code'@'%' 
IDENTIFIED BY 
'password_of_the_user_in_php_code';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

source:
http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server-366908.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try that. Do i need to open the port 3306 in my server currently its not openend. Will that be a problem

Comment: Ofcourse you need to open that.. Make sure you've added port 3306 under exception list in Windows Firewall

Comment: Thats connected now its a simple mistake.+1